# Not Able to Replace Space with Character in Bulk Name Update

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe

I have some images in a folder like

```
van-map-PE 100-1.png
van-map-PE 200-8.png
van-map-PE 160-2.png
van-map-PE 400-6.png
```

Now I want to remove all spaces between `PE xxx-` and replace it with `-` like

```
van-map-PE-100-1.png
van-map-PE-200-8.png
van-map-PE-160-2.png
van-map-PE-400-6.png
```

I used this command in Power shell

```
PS D:\imgs\png> get-childitem *.png | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.name.replace( "PE ","PE-")}
```

but I am getting this error

```
ForEach-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'RemainingScripts'. Cannot convert the "" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
At line:1 char:78
+ ... item *.png | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.name.replace( "PE ","PE-")}
+                                                                         ~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ForEach-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is correct. The problem is an unwanted character hidden at the end of your statement. Notice how the `~` in the error is underlining what appears to be emptiness after your code. You have an unwanted [Byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) after the final curly brace. Looking at your code in a hex editor reveals this:

[image]

### Resolution

Starting from the end of your code, press backspace until the closing curly brace is gone. This will ensure you've removed the BOM. Once the closing curly brace is removed, add it again. Alternatively,  copy this revised version of your statement:

```
gci *.png | % { ren $_ $_.name.replace(" ","-")}
```

### Additional information

`EF BB BF` (`ï»¿`) is the BOM for UTF-8. This problem is only present in your original post. Since your post has been edited, I do not see the BOM character in your Powershell code (although I don't see that it was explicitly removed via an edit). If you were to review the history of your original post, you will be able to capture the unwanted BOM.

Comment: I've got this feeling that I'm completely missing something here, but here it goes; Can you tell me how you can hexedit his code without access to his actual script file and not just the text pasted here? I don't see any link to such a file here. I'm just curious. +1 for your answer though.

Comment: I only copied the code that was posted, I did not have access to any other source.

Comment: Thank You for replying. 'The code that was posted' - is that 'I used this command in Power shell' ? That line has no trailing, hidden chars ?! It ends with the closing bracket ?

Comment: I'm glad you commented. This confused me, too, when reviewing my answer. The character was removed when the post was edited. I've modified my answer to include more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a take that should get this done for you. Others of course will have their take.

```
'van-map-PE 100-1.png',
'van-map-PE 200-8.png',
'van-map-PE 160-2.png',
'van-map-PE 400-6.png' | 
%{New-Item -Path 'D:\Temp\PngFiles' -Name "$_" -ItemType File}

Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp\PngFiles'


    Directory: D:\Temp\PngFiles


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                           
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                           
-a----        9/28/2018   8:59 PM              0 van-map-PE 100-1.png                                                           
-a----        9/28/2018   8:59 PM              0 van-map-PE 160-2.png                                                           
-a----        9/28/2018   8:59 PM              0 van-map-PE 200-8.png                                                           
-a----        9/28/2018   8:59 PM              0 van-map-PE 400-6.png  


Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp\PngFiles' | 
ForEach { 
    $NewFileName = $_.FullName -replace ' ','-'
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $NewFileName -Verbose -WhatIf
}


 Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp\PngFiles' | 
ForEach { 
    $NewFileName = $_.FullName -replace ' ','-'
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $NewFileName -Verbose -WhatIf
}
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\PngFiles\van-map-PE 100-1.png Destination: D:\Temp\PngFiles\van-map-PE-100-1.png".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\PngFiles\van-map-PE 160-2.png Destination: D:\Temp\PngFiles\van-map-PE-160-2.png".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\PngFiles\van-map-PE 200-8.png Destination: D:\Temp\PngFiles\van-map-PE-200-8.png".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\PngFiles\van-map-PE 400-6.png Destination: D:\Temp\PngFiles\van-map-PE-400-6.png".



Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp\PngFiles' | 
ForEach { 
    $NewFileName = $_.FullName -replace ' ','-'
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $NewFileName -Verbose # -WhatIf
}

Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp\PngFiles'


 Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp\PngFiles'


    Directory: D:\Temp\PngFiles


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                           
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                           
-a----        9/28/2018   8:59 PM              0 van-map-PE-100-1.png                                                           
-a----        9/28/2018   8:59 PM              0 van-map-PE-160-2.png                                                           
-a----        9/28/2018   8:59 PM              0 van-map-PE-200-8.png                                                           
-a----        9/28/2018   8:59 PM              0 van-map-PE-400-6.png
```